How do I solve for $x$ in the equation $a+bx\equiv0 \pmod 1$?
I met a problem in solving for $x$ in this equation $$a+bx\equiv0 \pmod 1,$$ where $a\in[0,1]$, $b \in \mathfrak{R}^+$, both $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers, and $x$ should be an integer.
In other words, this problem means to find $x$ such that $a+bx$ becomes an integer.
I tried to find a mathematical expression of the modulo. However, the suitable expression is hard to find. Then I realized that I should check whether the solution exists at first. So, I hope you can give some hints or clues for this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note that for any real number $x$, $x \mod 1$ is actually the fractional part of $x$, i.e. ${ x }$. So that means that for your problem, $\tau + \eta x$ must be integral

As far as I know there is no direct expression for $x$, but there are efficient methods for finding a solution. Can you give an example set of values of $\tau$ and $\eta$ for which you would like to solve it?

@Kraken Thank you for your reply. Yes. In other words, this problem means to find $x$ such that $\tau+x\eta$ becomes an integer.

Your problem should have been originally written like that, it makes the problem much easier to understand

@JaapScherphuis Thank you for your suggestion. I'd really like to find an expression for x based on the conditions provided. If that's not possible, then a numerical algorithm can be considered as an alternative.

Multiply to get rid of the denominators. Then you can just work with integers. $$\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{b_1}{b_2}x=y\in\mathbb Z$$ $$a_1b_2+a_2b_1x=y\cdot a_2b_2$$ $$a_1b_2+a_2b_1x\equiv0\mod a_2b_2$$

@mr_e_man Thanks. That is why I relax the constraints of $a$ and $b$ to be rational numbers. However, in my problem, $y$ is unknown. Additionally, proving $x$ exists and obtaining $x$ are the goals.

Indeed, $y$ doesn't matter. You are solving $$Cx\equiv D\mod E$$ where $C=a_2b_1$ and $D=-a_1b_2$ and $E=a_2b_2$ all are integers.

Write your fractions as $\,-a/c,\ b/d\,$ in lowest terms, so $\,\color{#0a0}{(a,c)\!=\!1\!=\!(b,d)}.\,$ Then
Lemma $\ \ \dfrac{b}d\,x\,\equiv\, \dfrac{a}c\pmod{\!1}\,\iff\, x\,\equiv\, \dfrac{a}{b}\color{#c00}{\dfrac{d}c}\pmod{\!d}\ \ \&\ \ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{d}c}\in\Bbb Z,\ $ by
$\dfrac{b^{\phantom{|}}\!\!}d\, x - \dfrac{a}c =n\!\iff bc\,x - ad = ncd\,$ $\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}{c\mid a}\:\!d\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{c\mid d}$.
Cancelling $\,c\,$ we get:  $\,\ b\,x - a\,\dfrac{d}c = nd\,\iff\, x\:\!\equiv\:\! \dfrac{a}{\color{#0a0}{b}}\,\color{#c00}{\dfrac{d}c}\,\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}d}$. $\ \ \small\bf QED$

Beware that above we mean  $,\color{#c00}{\dfrac{d}c} =$ quotient  $\color{#c00}{{\bf in}\ \Bbb Z},,$ vs. $,\dfrac{a}{\color{#0a0}b} := a\color{#0a0}{b^{-1}}=,$ quotient in $\Bbb Z_{\large\color{#0a0}d}$ (exists by $,\color{#0a0}{(b,d)!=!1})\ \ $

For fractions $,f,g\in\Bbb Q!:, \ f\equiv g\pmod{!!!{}_{\bf {\color{#c00}+}}:!\Bbb Z},$ means $,f-g\in \Bbb Z,,$ i.e. $,\bar f = \bar g,$ in $,\Bbb \langle Q,\bf {\color{#c00}+}\rangle/\langle\Bbb Z,\bf {\color{#c00}+}\rangle,$ (the quotient of their $\rm\color{#c00}{additive}$ groups), hence the $:!\bf {\color{#c00}+}:!$ subscript on the $!\bmod!$. $\ \ $

Thanks! I have two questions about your notations: (1) what does the "${!d:!\Bbb Z}$" mean in "$\pmod {!d:!\Bbb Z}$"? ; (2) what do those bars over $f$ and $g$ mean?
In addition, $n$ is not known before. I want to find $x$ that makes $a+bx$ an integer.  And $x$ should be an integer. Maybe you can explain your thoughts more directly to those who are not familiar with elementary number theory. Thanks again!

@Zer bars denote congruence classes $,\bar f = f+n\Bbb Z,$ in the additive quotient group $,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ = $\Bbb Q \bmod \Bbb Z,,$ i.e. rationals $!
\bmod 1.,$  If you don't know group theory then simply ignore that remark and read it more simply as $,f-g\in\Bbb Z,,$ and read $\bmod\Bbb d:!\Bbb Z:$ as $\bmod d.\  $ The answer finds all integer solutions for $,x.\ \ $

@ZeroHero I removed all uses of group theory (notation) in this answer. $\ \ $

That is more clear. Thanks a lot!

Note: This answer was given when $a$ and $b$ were stated to be real numbers. The question was later edited to make them rational.
$$ a+bx \equiv 0 \mod 1$$
Let's take as an example,
$$b = 0.55919290347074683016042813998599\\
a = 0.76360665363038166951461187296225$$
Let's explore the multiples of $b$ to see what fractional parts we can achieve and how small they can get. Those can then be used as building blocks to solve the equation.
The first multiple of $b$ to exceed $1$ is $2b$, so this gives us a smaller fractional part:
$$1*b \equiv 0.55919290347074683016042813998599\\
2*b \equiv 0.11838580694149366032085627997198$$
By combining these two we can make an even smaller fractional part. Take the first multiple of the smallest one that exceeds the largest:
$$1*2*b \equiv 0.11838580694149366032085627997198\\
2*2*b \equiv 0.23677161388298732064171255994396\\
..\\
5*2*b \equiv 0.5919290347074683016042813998599$$
which gives us
$$(5*2-1)b = 0.59192903470746... - 0.559192903470746...\\
9b = 0.03273613123672147144385325987391$$
Our two smallest fractions are now:
$$2*b \equiv 0.11838580694149366032085627997198\\
9*b \equiv 0.03273613123672147144385325987391$$
We can do the same trick again:
$$1*9*b \equiv 0.03273613123672147144385325987391\\
4*9*b \equiv 0.13094452494688588577541303949564\\
(4*9-3)*b \equiv 0.130944524946885... - 0.1183858069414...\\
33*b \equiv 0.01255871800539222545455675952366$$
Our two smallest fractions are now:
$$9*b \equiv 0.03273613123672147144385325987391\\
33*b \equiv 0.01255871800539222545455675952366$$
You repeat this process, taking the last two fractional parts to create a smaller one, a bit like the Euclidean algorithm. You get the following sequence of multiples of b with decreasing fractional parts:
$$1*b \equiv 0.55919290347074683016042813998599\\
2*b \equiv 0.11838580694149366032085627997198\\
9*b \equiv 0.03273613123672147144385325987391\\
34*b \equiv 0.01255871800539222545455675952366\\
93*b \equiv 0.00494002277945520491981701869707\\
245*b \equiv 0.00226135033297338930489429656755\\
642*b \equiv 0.00184402821946496299486587100558\\
1039*b \equiv 0.00142670610595653668483744544361\\
1436*b \equiv 0.00100938399244811037480901988164\\
1833*b \equiv 0.00059206187893968406478059431967\\
2230*b \equiv 0.0001747397654312577547521687577\\
7087*b \equiv 0.00010689718278534695422808071113\\
11944*b \equiv 0.00003905460013943615370399266456$$
This can go on indefinitely, unless $b$ happens to be rational.
While you do this, you also subtract as many of these as possible from your original equation until the right hand side is near enough to zero. The original equation is:
$$bx \equiv -a \equiv 1-a \equiv 0.23639334636961833048538812703775\\
bx \equiv 0.23639334636961833048538812703775$$
The subtracting process looks like this:
$$b(x-2) \equiv 0.23639334636961...-0.11838580694...\\
b(x-2) \equiv 0.11800753942812467016453184706577$$
$$b(x-2-3*9) \equiv 0.118007539428124... - 3*0.03273613123672...\\
b(x-29) \equiv 0.01979914571796025583297206744404$$
$$b(x-29-34) \equiv 0.01979914571796... - 0.01255871800539...\\
b(x-63) \equiv 0.00724042771256803037841530792038$$
$$b(x-63-93) \equiv 0.00724042771256... - 0.0049400227794552...\\
b(x-156) \equiv 0.00230040493311282545859828922331$$
$$b(x-156-245) \equiv 0.0023004049331... - 0.002261350332973...\\
b(x-401) \equiv 0.00003905460013943615370399265576$$
$$b(x-401-11944) \equiv 0.0000390546001... - 0.0000390546001...\\
b(x-12345) \equiv 0 $$
There may be rounding errors in at the end, but it suddenly jumps near enough to zero that it is clear that in this case the solution is $x=12345$.

Thanks a lot! That's a really good numerical method. After reading your answer, I think that If $a$ and $b$ are both assumed to be rational numbers, can I obtain an expression for x?
